# Kotlin: How to modify a value in a pair?

Tags: tuples, kotlin

Why can't I change the values in the pair:

```
var p: Pair<Int, String> = Pair(5, "Test")
p.first = 3
```

Error under `p.first`: Val cannot be reassigned

Answer (score 42, accepted):

[Pair](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin/-pair/index.html), like most data classes, is immutable. Its definition is effectively

```
data class Pair<out A, out B>(val first: A, val second: B)
```

If it were mutable, it could not be covariant in `out A` and `out B`, nor would it be safe to use as a Map key.

However, like other data classes, it can be [copied with changes](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/data-classes.html#copying).

```
p = p.copy(first = 3)
```